# How to open Pinterest and Linked iOS app for share something?

Tags: ios, post, share, linkedin-api, pinterest

I coding a iOS app, It need open Pinterest and LinkedIn to share something. (If user didn't install it, it will be open safari and share - post something).

I try to use some Schemes, but it didn't work. Maybe have anyway for do this.

I found some URL Schemes for share with Pinterest app. It worked for me:

```
NSString *sharingURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pinterestsdk.v1://pinit/?client_id=%@&source_url=%@&image_url=%@&app_name=%@&suggested_board_name=%@&description=%@",@"xxxxxxx", @"shareurl.com", @"shareurl.com/shareMedia.png", @"Your_App_Name", @"Board_Name", @"Your_Description"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharingURL]];
}
```

With LinkedIn, i researching for a best solution.

Oh, Maybe have way for share with LinkedIn app, when you press share on Safari browse, it have a option for LinkedIn, and it worked without signin (safari did not sign in LinkedIn before, just LinkedIn app.). But SDK of LinkedIn just support for REST API.

Thanks, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Opening a Pinterest User Profile

```
- (IBAction)openPinterestUser:(id)sender {

    // open the Pinterest App if available
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pinterest://user/juliav1"]]) {

        // opening the app didn't work - let's open Safari
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pinterest.com/versluis2000/"]]) {

            // nothing works - perhaps we're not online
            NSLog(@"Dang!");
        }
    }
}
```

> Opening a Pinterest Board

```
- (IBAction)openPinterestBoard:(id)sender {

    // open the Pinterest App if available
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pinterest://board/versluis2000/ios-projects"]]) {

        // opening the app didn't work - let's open Safari
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pinterest.com/versluis2000/ios-projects/"]]) {

            // nothing works - perhaps we're not online
            NSLog(@"Dang!");
        }
    }
}
```

> Opening a Pinterest Pin

```
- (IBAction)openPinterestPin:(id)sender {

    // open the Pinterest App if available
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pinterest://pin/76279787413881109"]]) {

        // opening the app didn't work - let's open Safari
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pinterest.com/pin/76279787413881109/"]]) {

            // nothing works - perhaps we're not online
            NSLog(@"Dang!");
        }
    }
}
```

Using Pintrest SDK

> Pin methods

```
- (void)getPinWithIdentifier:(NSString *)pinId
                      fields:(NSSet *)fields
                 withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                  andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;

- (void)createPinWithImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                         link:(NSURL *)link
                      onBoard:(NSString *)boardId
                  description:(NSString *)pinDescription
                  withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                   andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;

- (void)createPinWithImage:(UIImage *)image
                      link:(NSURL *)link
                   onBoard:(NSString *)boardId
               description:(NSString *)pinDescription
                  progress:(PDKPinUploadProgress)progressBlock
               withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

Here is the Pintrest IOS SDK link [pinterest/ios-pdk](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/)

> [1](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/): https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk

The PinterestSDK for iOS will allow you to authenticate an account with Pinterest and make requests on behalf of the authenticated user. For details on the supported endpoint,[visit the Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/).

Comment: Can It redirect to create Pin with some content?

Comment: As of May 20th 2013, Pinterest have released an iOS SDK for pinning content.

Check out their Developers site for more information.
https://developers.pinterest.com/

Comment: For More info, YOu can get form here.. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/

Comment: @Ninh, i have edited my code, check it and you find helpful then please upvote my answer

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Pinterest SDK answer mentioned above, LinkedIn provided a native iOS SDK that will facilitate sharing content through.

You can download it here: https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads

With additional documentation available here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: I tried it, but maybe it just support share by REST API. I looking for open their ios app and fill something to share like Pinterest.
With LinkedIn URL Schemes (and SDK), i found some Deeplink to open Profile, but nothing to share.

Comment: You can use the REST helper methods in teh SDK to send an API call to share content.  Look again at  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Click on the "iOS SDK" tab half-way down the page, and there's a full example of how to send a share in Objective-C provided.